# What does "what poor father couldn't dream of painting in two lifetimes" mean?

Tags: meaning

Margaret asks Armand about painter Vincent:

> Margaret: Did you know he was a genius? Well I did. And, so did my father. All his life he has tried
> so hard to be an artist. And, then this gruff awkward man without any proper training
> who'd only been painting a few years comes barging in and rushes off in a couple
> of hours **what poor father couldn't dream of painting in two lifetimes**.

What does "what poor father couldn't dream of painting in two lifetimes" mean?

Comment: "what" = "that which." "Father" is a proper noun with "poor" as an adjective.

Comment: @randomhead It's a run on sentence, please help me understand those highlighted text.

Comment: Margaret's father can't imagine himself painting as well as Vincent after _two_ lifetimes of trying, let alone the one lifetime he has actually spent doing so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what's confusing in that sentence is the verb. "Rushes off" is being used unusually to mean "creates hastily," so the whole phrase that you've highlighted works as an object to that verb. A simplified version of the sentence would be "This man ... comes barging in and *does* in a couple of hours what father couldn't *do* in two lifetimes."